# automated theorem proving program - where to start?

Tags: logic, theorem-proving

I'm a second year student with my discrete mathematics 2 assignment is to make an automated theorem prover. I have to make a simple prover program that works on Propositional Logic in 4 weeks (assuming that the proof always exist). I've googled so far but the materials there is really hard to understand in 4 weeks. Can anyone recommend me some book/site/open source code that is for beginners or some useful hints to start with? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note: I flagged this to be moved to the Computer Science site because they are much more on top of ATP over there.

It would be nice if you could include what you have looked at and why it does not help you. Then we can figure out what might be better for you. Also, if you have to write a program, then knowing what languages you know will help. Most of what I do with this is done in a functional language such as OCaml or F#, or a logic language such as Prolog or Mercury.

Have you seen "[Handbook of Practical Logic and Automated Reasoning](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~jrh13/atp/)" [(WorldCat)](http://www.worldcat.org/oclc/244767230) by John Harrison. I included the [(WorldCat)](http://www.worldcat.org/oclc/244767230) link so you can find the book in a local library as opposed to waiting to buy it which will eat up most of your time.

If you look you will find the [OCaml](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~jrh13/atp/) code at the bottom of the page, and F# [here](https://github.com/jack-pappas/fsharp-logic-examples/) and Haskell [here](http://code.google.com/p/haskellatp/issues/searchtips).

In case you haven't see the [ATP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automated_theorem_proving) or [Proof Assistant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_assistant) at Wikipedia, you might get a lead to some code and papers.

Comment: Thank for your open source links but i don't know F# and Haskell and OCaml so I think I'm gonna stick to C++. Anyway I found an interesting guy at http://arxiv.org/ftp/cs/papers/9301/9301110.pdf. i think i'm gonna play with him for a while.

Comment: @minhnhat93 Good paper. Paulson is one of the best in the field on the subject. You are aware the sample code is in ML which is a fuctional language and a predecessor to OCaml and F#? If you can get hold of "ML for the working programmer" by Paulson, it should help you more with understanding the code.

Comment: is there any particular reasons for these provers to be written mostly in functional languages and not in popular languages such as c, java, c#...? if ML is predecessor to OCaml and F# then i guess I need to be learning F# now.

Comment: I don't the history of theorem provers as much as I know about proof assistants. In short ML was created for LCF one of the first programs for working with theorems and is the parent of Caml, OCaml, F# and other languages. Since functional languages can written without side effects, it lends itself to being provable. With side effects in imperative languages, proving code is much harder.